# Binding internal DUT signal to interface and using it in monitor

Tags: interface, system-verilog, uvm

I have some internal DUT signals which I need to use in my Monitor. I tried to bind the interface and then use the virtual interface in monitor but the DUT values doesn't reflect on my interface.

testbench_top-

```
bind fifo1 : i_dut.fifo_inst.fifo1_inst exp_interface m1 (.fifo_out(out_dut1));
exp_interface exp_intf();

initial
     begin 
       uvm_config_db#(virtual exp_interface)::set(null, "*", "exp_intf", exp_intf);
end
```

interface file-

```
 interface exp_interface (
        output fifo_in,
        input fifo_out
    );
    endinterface
```

In monitor I am trying to access using-

```
if(exp_intf.fifo_out==1)
          $display("hello0---------------------");
```

but I don't see the dut value of out_dut1 (which is tied to 1) reflected on the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bind` statement just instantiates your interface of type `exp_interface` inside the instance you provided `i_dut.fifo_inst.fifo1_inst` with the instance name `m1`.

As a result, the path to your interface is `i_dut.fifo_inst.fifo1_inst.m1`. This is the one which you need to register.

In your case you instantiated yet another interface in the current scope which is not bound to any real signal. It is not needed.

Comment: ahhh... I felt there was some connection missing and now you got it. So I registered m1 and now able to get and see the DUT values. Thanks for that. This almost ruined my weekend.